# How to run python script on terminal without using python3?

Tags: macos, terminal, python-3.6

I have a problem: How can I run on terminal a script of python without using python3 before the name of script?

For example: 
For run my script I should write on terminal this:

```
$ python3 nameofthescript.py args
```

But I want that you to write this:

```
$ nameofthescript args
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, obviously rename the file

```
mv nameofthescript.py nameofthescript
```

Next, add this to the beginning of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Then make the file executable:

```
chmod +x nameofthescript
```

Now you should be able to run the file as:

```
./nameofthescript
```

If you want it to run from any directory, you have to move it to a directory inside your $PATH (usually /usr/local/bin):

```
mv nameofthescript /usr/local/bin
```